# RabbitMq Consumer.Received sometimes fires up and other times it doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

When I launch it in debugging mode it works just fine, but when I use Ctrl + F5 the Console.WriteLine(body) the text (body) doesn't get displayed but then again, when I launch it using Ctrl+ F5 **continuously**, it does get displayed few times.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                UserName = "guest",
                Password = "guest",
                HostName = "127.0.0.1",
                VirtualHost = "/"
            };

            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            var channel = connection.CreateModel();
            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

            consumer.Received += Consumer_Received;   

            channel.BasicConsume(
               queue: "Que.Console",
               autoAck: false,
               consumer: consumer);                                                                                           
        } 

   private static void Consumer_Received(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
        {   
            var body = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Body.Span);
            Console.WriteLine(body);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might lose the event handling in case of an Exception in the Received Event.

Use try-catch in your Received Event - to make sure it won't break.

```
private static void Consumer_Received(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
{   
    try
    {
        var body = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Body.Span);
        Console.WriteLine(body);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.mMssage);
    }
}
```